# Get all XAML files from compiled DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to load during runtime external XAML styles from third-party libraries (DLLs). Like in [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-load-skins-dynamically-in-wpf/) they use:

```
Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/WpfSkinSample;component/Skins/" + name + ".xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
```

to load the new style.

But I don't know the XAML names from the third-party library, so I'm searching for a way to get them and load them into my application.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**
Thanks to andyp, I did the following work out:

```
    public void LoadXaml(String Assemblypath)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Assemblypath);
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources");
        var resourceReader = new ResourceReader(stream);

        foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resourceReader)
        {
            if (new FileInfo(resource.Key.ToString()).Extension.Equals(".baml"))
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri("/" + assembly.GetName().Name + ";component/" + resource.Key.ToString().Replace(".baml", ".xaml"), UriKind.Relative);
                ResourceDictionary skin = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;
                this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(skin);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, used your code to work out what the magic URI was.

Comment: `ResourceReader` is `IDisposable` so a `using()` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can enumerate the embedded resources of an assembly like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("pathToYourAssembly");
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources");
var resourceReader = new ResourceReader(stream);

foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resourceReader)
    Console.WriteLine(resource.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to load the external xaml file with your code. I added the solution to my post.